# what is the ADA (Cardano crypto-currency) SDK?

Tags: ada, blockchain

I'am very new to the blockchain community and I have a new project that i'am starting to work on using the Cardano Blockchain and its crypto ADA.
I stumbeled upon the name "ADA SDK" and I tried to dig deeper and research it more but i can't find any clear information on what do you use it for exactly.
I know what is an SDK in general but what is an ADA SDK ?
Is it the development Kit you have to download to start working with ADA ? or what exactly ?
The few information that I found are that there an android/ios ada SDK that is used for a chatbot or something and I don't think it's the same thing i'm talking about or is it ?
I'm so sorry but I'am really confused is there anyone who could help me ? thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, Cardano SDK is a set of libraries for different languages which should make it easier to integrate with Cardano. You can take a look here https://github.com/input-output-hk/adrestia